# K&R Exe. 1-23 : Some Complications

Tags: c, comments

"Exercise 1-23. Write a program to remove all comments from a C program.
Don't forget to handle quoted strings and character constants
properly. C comments do not nest." K&R pg.34

Basically, I have two questions:

1)I'm completely new coding and I wanted to know if I'm at least thinking the problem the right way.

2)The code was built to ignore `//` till `\n` or `/*` till `*/`. But whit the `/*` comment it always leaves one `/`.

---

**Input:** `abc/*comment*/123`

**Output:** `abc/123`

---

**Input:** `abc/*123`

**Output:** `abc/`

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
char s[1000]; //Principal array
int countS; //Number of char in array

int deletSingleLineComments(void);
int deletMultiLineComments(void);

int main(void){
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        s[countS]=c;
        ++countS;
    }

    deletMultiLineComments(); //Function 1
    deletSingleLineComments(); //Function 2

    printf("\ns[]=\n%s\n\ncountS[]=%d\n",s,countS);
}



//Functions 1
int deletMultiLineComments(void){
    char t[1000];
    int i=0;
    int inComment=0;
    int diff=0;
    int a,b,c;

    while(i<=countS){ 
        t[i]=s[i];
        ++i;
    }
    i=0;

    while(i<=countS){

        if(t[i]=='/' && t[i+1]=='*'){ 
            inComment=1;
        }

        if(inComment==1){
            ++diff; //to equilibrate the number
        }

        if(inComment==0){
            s[i-diff]=t[i];
        }

        if(t[i]=='*' && t[i+1]=='/'){
            inComment=0;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    s[i-diff+1]='\0';
    countS=i-diff;

    printf("\nt[]=\n%s\n",t);
}



//Function 2
int deletSingleLineComments(void){
    int i=0;
    char t[1000];
    int inComment=0;
    int diff=0;

    while(i<=countS){
        t[i]=s[i];
        ++i;
    }
    i=0;

    while(i<=countS){

        if(t[i] == '/' && t[i+1] == '/'){
            inComment=1;
        }

        if(t[i]=='\n'){
            inComment=0;
        }

        if(inComment==1){
            ++diff;
        }

        if(inComment==0){
            s[i-diff]=t[i];
        }
        s[i-diff+1]='\0';
        ++i;
    }
    countS=i-diff;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to trace the execution of your program? Or even basic printf debugs? Learning and gaining experience in effective debugging is well worth the effort.

Comment: Do I need to install a debugger or I already have it? I'm coding in IOs El capitan with TextWrangler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(i<=countS){ t[i]=s[i];... }
```

Note that character strings are zero based. For example `"ABC"` has length `3`, it starts at zero index, and the last valid index is `2` (not `3`). Therefore you should change the condition to `i < string_length`

```
while(i < countS){ t[i]=s[i];... }
```

Also be careful when accessing `t[i+1]`, because while `i` is valid, `i+1` can be out of bound.

```
if (i < (countS - 1))
    if(t[i]=='/' && t[i+1]=='*')
```

In order to assign one string to another, you can introduce a second variable `k`, and increment `k` after each assignment. This method is easier (in my opinion) than using the `diff` variable and doing additions and subtractions.

In addition, rather than `char t[1000];`, you can use `char *t = malloc(countS);` to declare a temporary variable of length `countS`, then it has to be freed at the end with `free(t)`. If your compiler supports variable length array, you can just put `char t[countS]`.

Example:

```
char s[1000]; //Principal array
int countS; //Number of char in array

//Functions 1
void deletMultiLineComments(void) 
{
    char *t = malloc(countS);
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int inComment = 0;

    while (i < countS)
    {
        t[i] = s[i];
        ++i;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < countS) 
    {
        if (i < countS - 1)
        if (t[i] == '/' && t[i + 1] == '*') 
        {
            inComment = 1;
            i+=2;
            continue;
        }

        if (inComment == 1) 
        {
            if (i < countS - 1)
            if (t[i] == '*' && t[i + 1] == '/')
            {
                inComment = 0;
                i+=2;
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (inComment == 0) 
        {
            s[k] = t[i];
            k++;
        }

        ++i;
    }

    free(t);
    s[k] = '\0';
    countS = k;

    printf("mulitline comment removed %s\n", s);
}

//Function 2
void deletSingleLineComments(void) 
{
    char *t = malloc(countS);
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int inComment = 0;

    while (i < countS) 
    {
        t[i] = s[i];
        ++i;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < countS) 
    {
        if (i < countS - 1)
            if (t[i] == '/' && t[i + 1] == '/')
            {
                inComment = 1;
                i += 2;
                continue;
            }

        if (t[i] == '\n')
        {
            inComment = 0;
        }

        if (inComment == 0) 
        {
            s[k] = t[i];
            k++;
        }

        i++;
    }
    free(t);    
    s[k] = '\0';
    countS = k;

    printf("single comment removed %s\n", s);
}

int main(void) 
{
    //get input
    scanf("%s", s);

    countS = 0;
    while (s[countS]) countS++;

    deletMultiLineComments(); //Function 1
    deletSingleLineComments(); //Function 2
}
```